# Why does R.predict.svm return a list of the wrong size?

Tags: r, machine-learning, f#, svm

I am trying to use the R type provider to fit and predict a Support Vector Machines model. I was able to fit the model but when I try to predict the returned vector has the same length as the training vector, which it should not have.

I tried the equivalent code directly in R and the returned list has the correct length.

Why is this happening?

Here is an example:

```
open System
open RDotNet
open RProvider
open RProvider.stats
open RProvider.e1071

// Random number generator
let rng = Random()
let rand () = rng.NextDouble()

// Generate fake X1 and X2 
let X1s = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 10. * rand () ] // length = 10
let X2s = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> 5. * rand () ] // length = 10

let Z1s = [ for i in 0 .. 5 -> 10. * rand () ] // length = 6
let Z2s = [ for i in 0 .. 5 -> 5. * rand () ] // length = 6

// Build Ys
let Ys = [0;1;0;1;0;1;0;1;0;1]

let XMat =
    ["X1", box X1s; "X2", box X2s]
    |> namedParams
    |> R.cbind

let ZMat =
    ["Z1", box Z1s; "Z2", box Z2s]
    |> namedParams
    |> R.cbind

let svm_model =
    ["x", box XMat; "y", box Ys ; "type", box "C"; "gamma", box 1.0]
    |> namedParams
    |> R.svm

let svm_predict = R.predict(svm_model, ZMat)

let res =
    if svm_predict.Type = RDotNet.Internals.SymbolicExpressionType.IntegerVector then
        svm_predict.AsInteger()
        |> List.ofSeq
    else failwithf "Expecting a Numeric but got a %A" svm_predict.Type

printfn "The predicted values are: %A" res
// The predicted values are: [1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 2; 1; 1; 1; 2]
```

And here is the original R code:

```
library(stats)
library(e1071)

// Random number generator
x1 <- 10 * rnorm(10)
x2 <- 5 * rnorm(10)
x = cbind(x1, x2)

z1 <- 10 * rnorm(5)
z2 <- 5 * rnorm(5)
z = cbind(z1, z2)

zs <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)

svm_fit = svm(x=x,y=zs,type="C",gamma=1.0)
svm_pred = predict(svm_fit, z)

print(svm_pred)
1 2 3 4 5 
1 0 1 1 1 
Levels: 0 1
```

Comment: What does your original R code look like?

Comment: I added the R code. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I found that the second argument in `let svm_predict = R.predict(svm_model, ZMat)` is irrelevant. No matter what I enter there the result is the same. Even if I omit the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue might be when passing parameters to the `R.predict` function. I'm not an expert on SVMs, so I'm not sure what is the result this should give, but when I call it as follows, I get results similar to your R version:

```
let svm_predict = 
  namedParams ["object", box svm_model; "newdata", box ZMat ]
  |> R.predict
```

I think what's going on is that the R type provider infers some information about parameter names of the `predict` function, but is not able to figure out exactly what the second parameter is - and so rather than providing it as `newdata`, it provides it as something else.

Comment: Millions of thanks! I was stuck. I had actually tried to do something similar but I had not placed `box` before `svm_model`. I was assuming that since `svm_model` is of type `SymbolicExpression` boxing it was not necessary. On second thought, clearly all the tuples passed to `namedParams` must have the same type, namely `string*obj`.